# Book with Spectral Sequence Calculation of (Co)Homology of Klein Bottle?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

Is there a book (*A User's Guide to Spectral Sequences*? Brown's *Cohomology of Groups*?) that goes through a calculation of the (co)homology of the Klein bottle using a spectral sequence, treating it as a fiber bundle with base $S^1$ and also fiber $S^1$?

What I really need to compute is the (co)homology of a fiber bundle with base $T^2$ (the standard 2-torus) and fiber the Brieskorn homology sphere $\Sigma(3,4,5)$ using trivial outer action but a non-trvial element of $H^2(Q; Z(K))$ in the total group of the fiber bundle $E$'s fundamental group, but I'd like to start with a problem where I know the answer, as I've never done a spectral sequence calculation before.

Answer (score 3):

I am wholly ignorant of the literature, though I have heard Hatcher's notes are good to play with for practice. I will simply run through the computation for you. I apologize if I draw the SS differently than others, I forget sometimes how most people orient it --- you may have to swap the axes.

What you know is that there is a spectral sequence $$H^*(B;H^*(F;\Bbb Z)) \implies H^*(E;\Bbb Z).$$ This should be interpreted carefully: this is cohomology *with local coefficients*, where $H^*(F;\Bbb Z)$ is a $\pi_1 B$-module.

Remember that the Klein bottle may be defined as $K = S^1 \times [0,1]/(z,0) \sim (\overline z, 1)$, gluing the boundaries together by a reflection of the circle. This is in fact how the fiber bundle structure is defined; the projection to the base is the projection to the second factor $K \to [0,1]/0 \sim 1$, which is homeomorphic to a circle. Thus the monodromy action of $\pi_1 B = \Bbb Z$ is such that $1$ acts as reflection on the circle. The induced map of reflection on cohomology is the identity on $H^0(S^1)$ and $-1$ on $H^1(S^1)$.

Thus our spectral sequence starts with bottom line $H^*(S^1;\Bbb Z)$ (which is a copy of $\Bbb Z$ in degrees zero and one) and top line $H^*(S^1;\Bbb Z_-)$ (which is a copy of $\Bbb Z/2$ in degree one and nothing else). I encourage you to do the local coefficient computation on your own.

So our spectral sequence starts from $E_2$ page 
$$0 \; \;\;\;\;\; 0 \; \; 0 \; \;\; \;$$
$$0 \; \; \Bbb Z/2 \; \; 0 \; \; \cdots $$
$$\Bbb Z \; \; \Bbb Z \; \; 0 \; \; \cdots$$

But all differentials from here on out have bidegree $(k, 1-k)$, and since we are at the $E_2$ page they will all have first degree $k \geq 2$ --- so that the differentials are all automatically zero. Thus the spectral sequence collapes at $E_2$.

We thus obtain $H^0(K; \Bbb Z) = \Bbb Z$, as well as $H^1(K;\Bbb Z) = \Bbb Z$ and $H^2(K;\Bbb Z) = \Bbb Z/2$. You may check this is the same thing you would get from, say, Mayer-Vietoris.

Comment: $\begin{tabular}{lll}
\mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z} \\
\mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z} \\
\end{tabular}$

Comment: Sorry, I got behind with classes starting up again! I hope to post more tomorrow or Sunday.

I read Hatcher, and did the homology calculation for the Klein bottle. Spectral sequences for the homology of fiber bundles are beginning to make sense to me. It appears the $E^1_{p,q}$ page is a $C_*$ page and the $E^2_{p,q}$ page is an $H_*$ page.

I hope to post more tomorrow. I think I should be able to do the calculation for $\Sigma(3,4,5) \hookrightarrow E \twoheadrightarrow T^2$ with what I know now; thank you so much

Comment: I do everything with handlebody homology (deRham cohomology when I can), so I think I can see everything that's going on on the $E^1_{p,q}$ page pretty accurately, even with local coefficients.